# IP forward with Android 4.0 don't work

Tags: android, ip, forward

Il test a man in the middle attack (mitm) in wireless with a smartphone (HTC One X) and 2 computers. With the smartphone, the arp cache poisoning has correctly corrupted my 2 computers.

For the forwarding I have juste put "1" in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward. But ip forward don't work.

Shark sniffed in my smartphone, I sent packets with a computer, they are well arrived at my smartphone but they are not redirected to my other computeur.

Is there any others solutions for ip forwarding with android 4.0 ?

Comment: I know it's very late for it but i had this same problem. I had fixed it now. Link to answer: http://superuser.com/a/985733/505719